# How to output the standard error of odds ratio for proc logistic?

Tags: sas

When I use the proc logistic in SAS, in the output, it return the confidence of interval and p-value of the odds ratio, how can I output the standard error of the odds ratio?

```
proc logistic data=edu;                                                                                  
model school = age sex income/ clodds=wald orpvalue;
oddsratio age;
run;
```

The output likes

```
                 Odds Ratio Estimates and Wald confidence interval

                                      Point          95% Wald
                    Effect         Estimate      Confidence Limits  p-value

                    age              1.21         0.74      2.001   < 0.01
```

Answer (score 1):

- Tip: The documentation page [`Proc Logistic` `Details -> ODS Table Names`](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.4&docsetId=statug&docsetTarget=statug_logistic_details112.htm&locale=en) lists all the tables the procedure will produce for ODS. The `ODDSRATIO ... /CL=WALD ...;` statement creates an output table named `OddsRatiosWald`.

  - The `ODS TRACE ON` statement will also log the the table names that a Proc Step produces for ODS output.
- Save the table as an output data set using the `ODS OUTPUT` statement.

Example:

Code from SAS samples tweaked to save `ODS OUTPUT`.

```
* Example 76.4 Nominal Response Data: Generalized Logits Model;

data school;
   length Program $ 9;
   input School Program $ Style $ Count @@;
   datalines;
1 regular   self 10  1 regular   team 17  1 regular   class 26
1 afternoon self  5  1 afternoon team 12  1 afternoon class 50
2 regular   self 21  2 regular   team 17  2 regular   class 26
2 afternoon self 16  2 afternoon team 12  2 afternoon class 36
3 regular   self 15  3 regular   team 15  3 regular   class 16
3 afternoon self 12  3 afternoon team 12  3 afternoon class 20
;

ods trace on;
ods graphics on;

ods html file='logistic.html';

proc logistic data=school;
   freq Count;
   class School Program(ref=first);
   model Style(order=data)=School Program School*Program / link=glogit;
   oddsratio program / cl=wald;

   ods output OddsRatiosWald=or_program;
run;

proc print data=or_program;
  title "Logistic Odds Ratios CL=Wald output data";
run;

ods html close;
ods trace off;
title;
```

Output data as examined by viewtable in Base SAS

[image]

Comment: Richard, I think I have the same output like yours. In the table it has OddsRatioEst LowerCL UpperCl, I'm wondering how can we ouput the standard error of OddsRatioEst?

Comment: I'm not sure specifically, but look at `ODS OUTPUT ParameterEstimates=estimates`.  It might be there or computable from the output.